# The "up/down arrow" button on the site selector should say "Select a Filter"

Tags: bug, status-completed, ios-app

After tapping "All Sites" on the left sidebar in the app, the "All Sites" page is presented with a search field for finding a site. The up/down arrow button to the right of the search field brings up a popup titled "Select a Sort" with the options:

- All Sites
- Main Sites
- Meta Sites

This isn't a *sort*, but a *filter*. (I was actually looking for a real sort, and stumbled across this.)

Comment: It's also a little confusing that the default filter of "All sites" is actually just "Main sites" instead of "All sites". I wouldn't want it to change, but my brain had a disconnect with that for some reason. The meta site descriptions are also technically incorrect, but...

Comment: @TimStone, it looks to me like the default filter is "all sites", just like it says

Comment: @BenCollins Hm, doesn't show meta sites unless I select "all sites". Not that I want to see the meta sites by default, it's just a disconnect between the filter and view title.

Comment: Ah, ok.  I see it now.  I'll see what we can do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The action sheet title will be fixed in the next build or so.  I'll try to address the filter in the next one after that.